# Delete Rows based on Reference IDs

Tags: sql, sqlite, air, sql-delete

I am working on an AIR application that uses a local SQL lite DB to store information before it posts the data to a MySQL DB on the server at the end of each day. The data is posted in sets by user sessions. Once the data has posted i need to delete all rows associated with that session based on the session id. I have read many posts on this site and seen many ways to do this - unfortunately i have had little success getting them to run in SQL lite Manager - where i have been testing before i place it into the actionscript code. the following is one such attempt:

```
DELETE vendor_interest
  FROM vendor_interest v
INNER JOIN screen_view s on s.id = v.screen_view_id
                        and s.session_id = 44
```

The screen_view table has the reference to the session ID and to the vendor_interest table where i am trying to delete all the rows associated with the session.

Comment: SQLite doesn't allow the use of JOIN with the DELETE statement: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM vendor_interest 
WHERE screen_view_id IN (SELECT id FROM screen_view WHERE session_id = 44);
```

Comment: That does appear to work - thanx. 

So was it my attempt to use aliases?

Comment: Next issue - same item but for another table that is referenced two tables away from the screen_view table that holds the session_id ref.

I need to delete rows associated with a session from the vendor_watched table - connected to the video_view table. the following select statement gets me the rows:

     select vw.*
     from screen_view sv 
     left join video_view vv on (sv.id=vv.screen_view_id)
     left join vendor_watched vw on (vv.id=vw.video_view_id)
     where sv.session_id =48  and vw.id

thanx again